# Chatserver combined with TKinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, server

I'm trying to make a chatserver combined with TKinter for the GUI. In my client I'm outputting the messages from the server in this GUI via:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)
s.connect(("localhost", 12345))

w = MainWindow()
w.writeln(s.recv(512)) # this works

while w.update():
    socket_list = [s]
    read, _, _ = select.select(socket_list , [], [])
    for sock in read:
        if sock == s: # incomming message from server
            data = sock.recv(512)
            w.writeln(data)
```

What I'm trying to do is to check if there are any incomming messages from the server, and if so I output them. For some reason it gets stuck (in an infinity loop?). Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
The w.update() is always true, except when the window gets closed, so I guess this is my `mainloop`. I cannot use blocking socket i/o because this will block the GUI event loop. MainWindow() is part of the TKinter GUI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need more code than this. What is socket_list?

Comment: ...and MainWindow class

Comment: Is it part of client side code? If so, where is ``mainloop``? And what is socket_list? Incoming socket? Did you set ``socket.setblocking(0)``?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. Hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code remains unclear, however, I don't think that it is stuck in an infinite loop, rather it is probably blocked in the `select()` statement.

[**`select()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) takes a fourth argument for the timeout in seconds. If not supplied it will default to `None` and `select()` will block indefinitely. Calling `settimeout()` on the socket will not affect this. So `select()` is blocking your program whilst it waits for something from the server (whatever `server` actually is???? Shouldn't that be `s` instead?)

You can try setting a timeout for `select()`. Alternatively, look to non-blocking socket I/O.